# JavaScript Outputstream for request

Tags: javascript

I want to make a (further) request from `javascript`. Therefor i'd like to use an outputstream. It's just like using `XMLHttpRequest`, but I do not want to send just one completely known request, but open an outputstream where I can write bytes to.

A completed request header might be ok, but the content i would like to write to an outputstream.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by-

`A completed request header might be ok, but the content i would like to write to an outputstream.`

But, here is the answer from what I've understood. You can use a websocket to have persistent connection to the server(since u want to make a further request)

You can do something like this-

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocolOne");

exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
```

Check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Examples) regarding the same. And more on [Websockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Yes it seems to be the answer for my question. I will try it out! Thx a lot!

Comment: @user7372914 Good to know. Please mark the solution as the answer if you feel its resolved. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: It was good to know, to recognize that there is a Websocket and to find out how it works later on. It is surely the right way for my requirement. I use this implementation. However it did not solve my concrete problem: Within my WiFi i hat eventually occuring delays for few seconds when tried to send next bytes. This behaviour didn't change through Websocket. But later on it turned out, that this "feature" does only occure on my Smartphone (LG G3) ! I could not reproduce it on a laptop and even another smartphone (Galaxy S5 mini).

Comment: Maybe it has to do with different Android Version?! I did not really check.